# How to do authentication with React JS, Redux and Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, reactjs, redux

New to react js, redux and express.

I've made a simple login / register application using react js, redux, webpack and express. Currently the views / components are created and working.

I need to be able to store users information, "email" and "password" is all that's required to register.

Are there any examples of this I could look at implementing into my solution?

Comment: Do you want to store these information in a Database, or Session (Backend), or have them available in the frontend in your react app ?

Comment: If possible to have them available in the frontend in the react app

Comment: Is it better for me to use a database like MongoDB?

Comment: It's personal preference. Use what you want. I personally use mysql.

Comment: If my answer helped you, accept it as an answer so other people also know it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure if this is what you are looking for but you could do the following in your react component:

**NOTE** this is only an example how to do it without isomorphic javascript

```
...
componentDidMount(){
  this.getUserInitData()
}
...
getUserInitData(){
  // here you make a simple AJAX request to the server to get the data
  $.get('/api/get/user/init', function(result){
     console.log(result)
     // now result contains whatever information your server will respond with
     // this could be your user authentication data for example.
     // Now you can go ahead and store the result into your state
  });
}
```